# JavaScript error, "object doesn't support this property or method"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Why? This is driving me nuts???

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#slides1').bxSlider({
            prev_image: '/Public/Images/btn-arrow-left.jpg',
            next_image: '/Public/Images/btn-arrow-right.jpg',
            wrapper_class: 'slides1_wrap',
            margin: 0,
            auto: true,
            auto_controls: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have no idea about this, but, maybe its .boxSlider()  ?

Comment: @ Francisco bxSlider is a plugin...
@eberswine:  Are you sure you are including the plugin?  You should have a script tag with the src = jquery.bxslider2.0.1.min.js

Comment: Are you including jQuery and the plugin?

Comment: yes, in another file, I have the actual meat and potatoes of the script.. But this is just a small controller...

Comment: well, there's nothing wrong with what you posted, so it has to be somewhere else.  Do you have firebug or chrome to tell where the error occurred?

Comment: Deleted my post as it wasn't your answer.  Post your answer and accept it.

Comment: I wouldn't mind seeing some HTML

Comment: @Ryan:  You can see a working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/mDs4t/

Comment: A working version doesn't really help diagnose what's wrong with a non-working version.

Comment: The author found out it was another issue locally.  I deleted my answer, but I guess I should leave it in there so others don't think it's not resolved.  sorry.

Answer (score 2):

(posting as answer so I can format/etc.)

I put your code (slightly modified) into jsFiddle and it's working with no errors...

http://jsfiddle.net/mDs4t/

As long as you have the list setup right and you are including jQuery and bxSlider plugin at the top of the page there should be no problems.  As stated in my previous comment, the code posted here seems to be bug free.

Comment: I think it might because I am testing it from SVN locally on IE 8.. If I publish the file, then it is fine.. It is just when I am locally testing it??? Thanks so much for the feedback!

Comment: @eberswine: When you say you are testing it from SVN, what do you mean? I am not clear on how you could read files directly out of an SVN repository. Perhaps this is commonly done, but I am not familiar with this.

Comment: That's odd... Are you using IIS and maybe it's not loading the local script?  If you had Firebug or Chrome it would tell you if it can't load one of the plugins.  IE8 may have this option as well, but I don't have IE to test with right now.

Comment: Sorry, I am just running it from SVN on my asp dev. server (local)